# Binding UIElement to local Data

Tags: binding, silverlight-4.0, uielement

I am having a class "BoolValue" where i declare a bool value and convert this into Dependency Property(Hope me had done that correct)
Now in xaml where im having a checkbox wants to check/uncheck depending on bool value.
Me attching the whole code guys, pls help.

```
<StackPanel Height="287" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,65,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="309" DataContext="xyz" >
  <CheckBox Content="" Height="71" Name="checkBox1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCkecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And here is the class

```
public class BoolValue : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {        
        private bool _isCkecked;

        public bool IsCkecked
        {
            get { return _isCkecked; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _isCkecked)
                    return;

                _isCkecked = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsCkecked");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property);
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            //handler(this, args);
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, args);
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: How have you set up the `DataContext` for your view?

Comment: Just for the record, you're not converting to dependency property, you're rising PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual `DataContext` of your `StackPanel`? Looks like you're looking for property change but in different `DataContext`.

Providing `BoolValue` is your CheckBox's `DataContext`, below should work:

```
public class BoolValue : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    private bool isChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return isChecked; }
            set
            {
                if (isChecked != value)
                {
                    isChecked = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                }
            }
        }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            // take a copy to prevent thread issues
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}
```

XAML:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```